# Optional "name" in parameter-list?

Tags: c++, templates

`template < parameter-list > declaration`

Each parameter in parameter-list may be:

- a non-type template parameter;
- a type template parameter;
- a template template parameter.

Minutes ago, I found

- `template<typename>/*(a type template parameter)*/`
- `template<int>/*a non-type template parameter*/`

are legal in some cases.

So, syntax is like:

- a type template parameter;

  - typename name(optional)
- a non-type template parameter;

  - type name(optional)
- ...

Here is an example

```
template <typename T>
class ArrayList
{
    std::vector<T> vec;
public:
    template<class> // Mark!
    class Ref {
        ArrayList<T> *array;
        int position;
    public:
        Ref(ArrayList<T> *a, int pos):array(a), position(pos) {};
        Ref<T> &operator=(T v) {
            if (array->vec.size() <= position)
                array->vec.resize(position+1);
            array->vec[position] = v;
        }
        operator T() const {
            if (array->vec.size() <= position)
                throw std::exception();
            return array->vec[position];
        }
    };
    Ref<T> operator[](int p) {return Ref<T>(this, p); }; 
};
```

I know similar idiom in function's parameter `type fun(type) {}`, the only usage of it is we don't need the `name`, `type` is enough here.

My question is:

1. In the implementation of `Ref`, What is the benefit of `template<class>` instead of `template<class T>` or `template<class U>`. I guess that it is because we don't need extra `T/U` here(Precisely, it is `U`, because extra `T` will cause shadowing error) `template <typename T> class ArrayList`
2. What're the other benefits of the idiom?(Of course, perhaps no other benefits)
3. Except for injected class, when will we exclude the redundant `name` in `parameter-list`. I hope to see more applications.

Comment: One example of when you leave out the name is if you add an extra typename = void and use SFINAE on that parameter to select the correct specialization.

Comment: You know, after writing one example, I'm starting to think this may be too broad.

Comment: Emmm, do you refer to `tag dispatch` I don't think so. As an idiom, `tag dispatch` is not broad to be treated as an example here. If you refer to my question is too broad, I do agree :P

Answer (score 1):

1. In your particular example there is no benefit whatsoever. It makes `Ref` a member template for no good reason.
2. The benefit, if you can call it that, is the same as with function parameters, if we treat templates as meta-functions. We can signal that the parameter is ignored, and doesn't affect the resulting specialization. You can see it in tag dispatch code. For instance:

   ```
   template<typename> struct tag{};

   template<typename T>
   void do_foo_for(tag<T>) = delete;

   void do_foo_for(tag<int>) {
     // Do stuff
   }

   void do_foo_for(tag<std::string>) {
     // Do stuff
   }

   template<typename T>
   void foo() {
     do_foo_for(tag<T>{});
   }
   ```

   In the above, we use that `tag` template to create a cheap type with which to perform overload resolution. This is often done when we want the implementation of a template function do differ based on the type parameter. Since overloading is generally more robust than function template specialization, we overload based on the different types generated from the `tag` template. The type is important to the various overloads, but for the template itself the name of the type is not at all important, so we don't bother naming it.

   The uses of tag dispatch are too broad to describe here, so the above is a bit of a toy example. But it demonstrates how a function may be dispatched on a "type".

Comment: I know `tag dispatch` but didn't think of it lol. Thanks for your answer : )

Answer (score 1):

> Except for injected class, when will we exclude the redundant name in parameter-list. I hope to see more applications.

Another example of use is with `class`/`struct` template specialization.

Suppose you want to write a custom type traits to know if a type is a `std::vector` of something.

You can write it as follows

```
template <typename>
struct isVect : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct isVect<std::vector<Ts...>> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

So the default is "isn't a vector" but when the type is in form `std::vector<Ts...>`, become "is a vector".

Observe that you need receive the type but only in the specialization you need know something about it.

You can write the general version explicating an identifier of the template type

```
// ................V  you can add a type identifier, but why?
template <typename T>
struct isVect : public std::false_type
 { };
```

but you don't you use it, so why explicit the name?